# java.util.NoSuchElementException No Such Element Exception

Tags: java

New to Java - just trying to get a handle on it. The program is executing as follows:

```
What's your age?23
23
What's your name?Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at king.getName(king.java:25)
    at king.main(king.java:9)
```

The code it is trying to run is below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class king {



    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(getAge());
        System.out.println(getName());
    }

    public static int getAge(){
        System.out.print("What's your age?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String age = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();
        int numberAge = Integer.parseInt(age);
        return numberAge;

    }

    public static String getName(){
        System.out.print("What's your name?");
        Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = newScanner.next();
        newScanner.close();
        return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use `scanner.close()` <- source of your error!

remove the lines `scanner.close()` and `newScanner.close()`

From Java DOCs:

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source
>   implements the Closeable interface.

Which means it closes the `System.in` - bad choice!

From source code of `Scanner.java` in JDK, `throwFor()` is:

```
private void throwFor() {
    skipped = false;
    if ((sourceClosed) && (position == buf.limit()))
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else
        throw new InputMismatchException();
}
```

Clearly, if we have reached the end of input, OR if the source is closed, then we get the `NoSuchElementException()`. I am pretty sure the one at [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/P9ZBcH) has happened because of `position == buf.limit()` rather than `sourceClosed`

Comment: This seems to be working, but now eclipse is whinging about resource leak?

Comment: @Ravin I do not see anything wrong with "resource" leak in your code.

Comment: @Aniket I get the same error after removing the scanner.close(), see here http://ideone.com/P9ZBcH

Comment: @Aniket wierd, can not explain this. well if the OP says it worked then im fine with that.

Comment: @MeNoMore see the edit! I pretty much think that was the cause!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class King {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(getAge(scanner));
    System.out.println(getName(scanner));
  }

  public static int getAge(final Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.print("What's your age?");
    final String age = scanner.next();
    final int numberAge = Integer.parseInt(age);
    return numberAge;
  }

  public static String getName(final Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.print("What's your name?");
    final String name = scanner.next();
    return name;
  }
}
```

Also note that java classes should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

I think alraedy @Aniket has given a very good answer.

- First of all instead of `import java.util.*;` you can use `import
  java.util.Scanner;` so it will not import unnecessary classes.
- Second thing is that you can have a single `Scanner` like i have shown in the example.(so you can close it)

  ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class SO6 {
       static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       public static void main(String[] args){
           System.out.println(getAge());
           System.out.println(getName());
           scanner.close();
       }

      public static int getAge(){
          System.out.print("What's your age?");
          String age = scanner.next();
          int numberAge = Integer.parseInt(age);
          return numberAge;

      }

      public static String getName(){
          System.out.print("What's your name?");
          String name = scanner.next();
          return name;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @MeNoMore it works on my machine, i am using eclipse juno, jdk7.0

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to avoid NoSuchElementException you should perform Scanner.hasNext() check before using Scanner.next(). Other comments especially about using single scanner are also useful.

Comment: +1 for the `hasNext()` - it avoids the case of `pos == buf.limit()`